# Xen console access from the web

Tags: xen, console

Slicehost offers this, but I was wondering if there is a program out there that will do this (make a domU console available in a web browser).

If not, where would you start in putting together one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blog post from SliceHost](http://www.slicehost.com/articles/2006/9/18/ajax-console-for-your-slice)

[Software they're solution is based upon (ajaxterm)](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/)

if you make something, you should release it with a FOSS license :P

Answer (score 1):

you can use 3rd party open source product for doing such even

www.enomaly.com/